# Python regex - wierd behavior - findall doesnt match regex101

Tags: python, regex

(I believe the problem is in (?s).*? just btw)

I need to extract some functions from files.

I have this code:

```
pattern = "^\s*[a-zA-Z_]?.*void\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*\((?s).*?\).*?$"
objekt = re.findall(re.compile(pattern,re.MULTILINE), string)
```

where string is

```
extern inline void
lineBreak              (     void     )

;


extern      inline void           debugPrintf
(
const int level,
          const char        *  const                    format,
...)
{
return NULL;
}

extern void
debugPutc
(
const int level
,
const int c)
;
```

it returns however

```
extern inline void
lineBreak              (     void     )

;


extern      inline void           debugPrintf
(
const int level,
          const char        *  const                    format,
...)
{
return NULL;
}

extern void
debugPutc
(
const int level
,
const int c)
```

while when I am debugging at regex101 it returns 3 functions that I need to extract.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/uR8pD2/3)

Does anyone know where is the problem please? Thank you.

EDIT:

Just by the way before that I had this pattern:

```
"^\s*[a-zA-Z_]?.*void\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*\((?:\s*?.*?\s*?)*\)\s*?$"
```

and everything was working fine, except there was catastrophic backtracking and didnt work for other types then void (like double)

Comment: You should generally use a raw string `r"..."` for regexp.

Comment: Thanks, but it still wont solve the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's the `(?s)` that's messing you up.  In most flavors that support inline modifiers, you can insert `(?s)` anywhere in the regex, and single-line mode will start at that point and remain in effect until the end of the regex unless you turn it off with `(?-s)`.  If it's inside a group, the mode will reset when the group ends.  Alternatively, you can use a mode-modified group (a non-capturing group with an embedded mode modifier): `(?s:...)`.

But Python is not nearly so flexible.  It doesn't support mode-modified groups, and an inline modifier always affects the whole regex, no matter where you place it.  As [Markus said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719482/20938), the solution is to use `[\S\s]*?` instead (an idiom often used in JavaScript regexes, which have no singleline/DOTALL mode at all).

I also recommend that you use Python's raw string notation for regexes:

```
pattern = r"^\s*.*void\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*\([\s\S]*?\).*?$"
```

Comment: Thank you :) really appriciate it

Answer (score 3):

It says in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) that

> Note that the `(?x)` flag changes how the expression is parsed. It should be used first in the expression string, or after one or more whitespace characters. If there are non-whitespace characters before the flag, the results are undefined.

Other strange things seems to happen for the other flags. `.` at the start of the pattern was affected by the `(?s)` at the end, on the second and subsequent matches.

Python does not have any way to turn off the flags, once set. And there is no way to scope the flags. (In Perl and some other flavors, you can use scoped `(?s:.*?)` and disable `(?-s)`)

Another way to write the pattern, that would have the effect you seek:

```
pattern = r"^.*?\bvoid\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\s*\([\S\s]*?\).*$"
```

- `\b` matches a word boundary. Between a word character (A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and "_"), and a non-word character.
- `[\S\s]` will match any non-whitespace OR whitespace character. That is, any character, including linebreaks.

Comment: There's no `(?x)` in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the pattern, I at the end too changed the pattern to match the same thing, though I am still curious where is the problem in the old one. But still, I really appriciate your help. And that [\S\s] is genius :) didnt though about this.